# Generalization of Euclid's Lemma for Powers of Coprimes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

The generalized Euclid's lemma states that for $a,b,c\in \mathbb{Z}$, if $a|bc$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then $a|c$. Now, from this, can we prove that for $i,j\in \mathbb{N^*}$ if $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $a^i|b^jc$, then $a^i|c$? I actually even want to know if it's true if we let $i,j \in \mathbb{Q}$ provided $a^i,b^j \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first statement:

Let $m = a^i$ and $n = b^j$.

Then by the unique prime decomposition, and the fact that $a,b$ have no primes in common, we conclude that $m,n$ have no primes in common either. Thus: $gcd(m,n) = (gcd(a,b))^{\min({i,j})} = gcd(a,b) = 1$. But then:

$$m \vert nc \Rightarrow m \vert c$$

For the case where $i, j \in \mathbb{Q}$ we work similarly, as the fact that $a,b$ have no primes in common still implies that $m,n$ don't have any primes in common either. Granted, some of their powers in their corresponding decompositions may be reduced, but no common primes will show up, even after "fractional" (rational) exponentiation.

Comment: For your second statement, did you mean to write that: $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Why is it true that $\gcd(a^i,b^j)=\gcd(a,b)$? And yes, I mean, $a^i,b^j \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: This is not generally true, but it is true in this case by the unique prime decomposition. If $a,b$ have no primes in common then $a^i, b^j$ have no primes in common either. Does that make sense?

Comment: Hmm, because the prime decomposition of $a$ is just 'similar' to the prime decomposition of $a^i$ up to the list of primes?

Comment: Exactly! As a matter of fact, the only thing changing is that every prime in $a$ now comes with $i$ copies. For example: say $a = 12 = 2^2*3^1$ then $a^5 = 2^{10}*3^5$

Comment: Phew, that seems pretty simple. I wonder why things like these still escapes me. Thanks.

Comment: You are very welcome, glad I could help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56559/discussion-between-pellenthor-and-kurome).